# Filter Algolia Autocomplete by facet

Tags: javascript, arrays, autocomplete, algolia

I'm having an array of tags associated to an article (right side) and also added these tags as facet (left side), to group them:

[image: algolia index]

My autocomplete setup looks like this

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    hint: false
},[{
    source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {
        hitsPerPage: 5,
        facetFilters: 'tags'
    }),
    displayKey: 'tags',
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
            return suggestion._highlightResult.tags[0].value;
        }
    }
    }
]);
```

The problem I can't fix is that the tags are displayed as groups. So if I search for "Recht", I get this suggestion dozen of times.

[image]

I tried a few things I could find here and on GitHub but nothing allowed me to filter the autocomplete by the facet values. So if I enter "Recht" it should only appear once and not as often as it occurs within an article. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your index to de-duplicate results with the `distinct` attribute.

You can read more about it in our documentation https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/ranking/distinct/#distinct-for-de-duplication

Is it this you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If I select any of the values it still outputs the whole array (from screenshot 1: Erbe,Nachfolge,Schnekung). So, if I would select "Erbe", it would still output the rest of the array as well. My workaround now was to create a new index and not use the tags as facet. Little "messy", but works for my current case. I found no other way yet.